# How do I turn off automatic workspace building in C++ Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-cdt

I use Eclipse for C++ project. I have disable the building automatically in windows, but it still build workspace when I save the project. How can I do?

Comment: What do you mean by _"disable the building automatically in windows"_? Disabled _Project > Build Automatically_ or _Project > Properties: C/C++ Build: Behavior: Build on resource save (Auto build)_?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Disable the building automatically in window, then restart Eclipse, and the disable operation will work.